# How to add iOS geolocation keys for ngCordova Geolocation plugin?

Tags: ios, geolocation, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

How do I use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` when using ngCordova Geolocation plugin? Do I even need to use it? I mean is it even necessary because for native iOS 8 SDK and for Titanium SDK, there's a way to do this. But I installed the ngCordova plugin and I just got the coordinates. Basically the ngCordova geolocation just worked. So basically I'm just making sure if it's necessary because I need the Apple Store to approve my app. So is it?

For example in native iOS, see this picture: http://s2.postimg.org/8z01f9cvt/geolocationiosplist.png